# Writing a lot of data in cassandra in one query

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra

I have made a program that get data in one of my cassandra table and query twitter API to get the followers and friends of one user. I safe all the id in a set and then when I get all the followers/friends I write that into Cassandra.

The problem is one of the user got 1M24 followers and when I executed this code the size of the set kind of generate a writing error into cassandra.

```
def get_data(tweepy_function, author_id, author_username, session):
    if tweepy_function == "followers":
        followers = set()
        for follower_id in tweepy.Cursor(API.followers_ids, id=author_id, count=5000).items():
            if len(followers) % 5000 == 0 and len(followers) != 0:
                print("Collected followers: ", len(followers))
            followers.add(follower_id)
        query = "INSERT INTO {0} (node_id, screen_name, centrality, follower_ids) VALUES ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})"\
            .format("network", author_id, author_username, 0.0, followers)
        session.execute(query)
    if tweepy_function == "friends":
        friends = set()
        for friend_id in tweepy.Cursor(API.friends_ids, id=author_id, count=5000).items():
            if len(friends) % 5000 == 0 and len(friends) != 0:
                print("Collected followers: ", len(friends))
            friends.add(friend_id)
        query = "INSERT INTO {0} (node_id, screen_name, centrality, friend_ids) VALUES ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})"\
            .format("network", author_id, author_username, 0.0, friends)
        session.execute(query)
```

As asked I add my schema:

```
table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                    {0} (
                        node_id bigint ,
                        screen_name text,
                        last_tweets set<text>,
                        follower_ids set<bigint>,
                        friend_ids set<bigint>,
                        centrality float,
                        PRIMARY KEY (node_id))
                        """.format(table_name)
```

Why did I get a writing error? How to prevent it? Is that a good way to safe data into Cassandra?

Comment: what is your schema ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `follower_ids` and `friend_ids` as Set (Collection)

**Limitation of Collection in Cassandra :**

- The maximum size of an item in a collection is 64K or 2B, depending
  on the native protocol version.
- Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying because
  Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety. The collection is not
  paged internally, collections are designed to
  store only a small amount of data.
- Never insert more than 64K items in a collection.
  If you insert more than 64K items into a collection, only 64K of them will be queryable, resulting in data loss.

You can use the below schema :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    node_id bigint ,
    screen_name text,
    last_tweets set<text>,
    centrality float,
    friend_follower_id bigint,
    is_friend boolean,
    is_follower boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((node_id), friend_follower_id)
);
```

Here `friend_follower_id` is friendid or followerid, if friend then mark `is_friend` as `true` and if follower then mark `is_follower` as `true`

Example :

```
If for node_id = 1 
   friend_ids = [10, 20, 30]
   follower_ids = [11, 21, 31]
```

Then your insert query will be :

```
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_friend) VALUES ( 1, 10, true);
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_friend) VALUES ( 1, 20, true);
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_friend) VALUES ( 1, 30, true);
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_follower) VALUES ( 1, 11, true);
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_follower) VALUES ( 1, 21, true);
INSERT INTO user(node_id , friend_follower_id , is_follower) VALUES ( 1, 31, true);
```

If you want to get all friendids and followerids then query :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE node_id = 1;
```

You will get this :

```
node_id | friend_follower_id | centrality | is_follower | is_friend | last_tweets | screen_name
---------+--------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------
       1 |                 10 |       null |        null |      True |        null |        null
       1 |                 11 |       null |        True |      null |        null |        null
       1 |                 20 |       null |        null |      True |        null |        null
       1 |                 21 |       null |        True |      null |        null |        null
       1 |                 30 |       null |        null |      True |        null |        null
       1 |                 31 |       null |        True |      null |        null |        null
```

Source :
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

Comment: I don't really understand the new schema you are proposing. In my sets follower_ids I was storing all the ids of the people who followed my author and in my set friend_ids I did the same thing but using the people my author was following. So at the end  I had two collections of ids.

Comment: @mel details added to my answer

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is that the best way to store a collection?

Comment: When your collection size is huge, Instead of using collection always use schema like mine.